# Why my arduino serial to LCD gets stuck after 26 loop?

Tags: c, arduino, serial-port, lcd

I get a float from raspberry pi (via struct module) and my sketch only shows the data on an LCD screen.

After 26 corrects loop, on the 27th, the Arduino crashes.

Can you tell me what's wrong with the 27th?

- Changing delay from 20ms to 1s: NOK
- Put the byte pointer out of the function: NOK

```c
float f;

void getFloat(){
  byte *fdata = (byte *) &f;
  while(Serial.available() <= 4){}
  Serial.readBytes(fdata,4);
  }

void loop() {
  // set the cursor to column 0, line 1
  // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Ready to receive");
  getFloat();
  AZ=f;
  getFloat();
  AL=f;
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Moving            ");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  // print the number of seconds since reset:
  lcd.print("AZ");
  lcd.print(String(AZ));
  lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
  lcd.print("; AL");
  lcd.print(String(AL));
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("ok");
}
```

At the 27th, the arduino no longer acknoledge the data and the LCD shows :
==ving
AZy    ; AL0.00=

=== Resolution ===

Before, I have to send twice the floats via the next code to get the last if not, I get the previous data on my arduino but i think the limitation comes from there :

```
  def sendFloatToArduino(self,data):
    self.serial.write(struct.pack('<f', data))
    self.serial.flush()

  def pointer(self,AZ,AL):
#send the data
    print("AZ : "+str(AZ)+" ; AL : "+str(AL))
    self.sendFloatToArduino(AZ)
    self.sendFloatToArduino(AL)
    self.sendFloatToArduino(AZ)
    self.sendFloatToArduino(AL)
#wait for ack
    while (self.serialArduino.in_waiting==0):
      pass
    print(self.serialArduino.readline())
```

After deleting the double sending, everything is fine.

Comment: 1.What do you mean by "NOK Put the byte pointer out of the function : NOK"?
2.Are you watching the output from raspberry pi? it may have some errors

Comment: No, I mean that it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try using dtostrf https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html#ga060c998e77fb5fc0d3168b3ce8771d42

Comment: instead of String(AZ)

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out the problem, but you can try the following code. It's stronger I think.

```
float getFloat()
{
    float res;
    while (Serial.available() < sizeof(res))
        ;
    Serial.readBytes((char*)&res, sizeof(res));
    return res;
}

void loop()
{
    // ...
    AZ = getFloat();
    AL = getFloat();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What do you think about `return res;`? And as in the OP I don't understand waiting until five or more bytes available whilst 4 are needed.

Comment: Thanks but sadly, the readBytes parameters shoud be char[] or byte[]. that's why I was going with a pointer. so i have to adapt with `byte *fdata = (byte *) &res;` but it doesn't worked

Comment: @Fardouk You should apply a typecast. This answer was not intended to fix the problem but just make your code more pretty.  We don't see a problem right now in the provided code, so please insert `Serial.println();` extensively to elaborate the variables' values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

The problem is not about the parsing as you said but with the LCD display.

I've tried converting floats to array and geting only 16 characters:

```
  char str[16];
  AZ=getFloat();
  AL=getFloat();
  char buffer1[20];
  char buffer2[20];
  dtostrf(AZ,7,5,buffer1);
  dtostrf(AL,7,5,buffer2);
  for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
    if (i>1){
      str[i]=buffer1[i-2];
      str[i+8]=buffer2[i-2];
    }
  }
  Serial.println(str);
```

But I get this on serial output : `AZ358.54AL48.544\x12.BBHE\xb3CGm=\r\n` => fixed with `\0`
I think the problem is elswhere : I have to send twice the floats via the next code to get the last if not, I get the previous data on my arduino but i think the limitation comes from there :

```
  def sendFloatToArduino(self,data):
    self.serial.write(struct.pack('<f', data))
    self.serial.flush()

  def pointer(self,AZ,AL):
#send the data
    print("AZ : "+str(AZ)+" ; AL : "+str(AL))
    self.sendFloatToArduino(AZ)
    self.sendFloatToArduino(AL)
    self.sendFloatToArduino(AZ)
    self.sendFloatToArduino(AL)
#wait for ack
    while (self.serialArduino.in_waiting==0):
      pass
    print(self.serialArduino.readline())
```

Comment: This was the problem, deleting the double send solved it. Thanks to you, I don't wanna put to much code but i should have do. I put it resolved.

Comment: Well, you should move these into your question by editing it since these are not answers. Others will also remind you if I didn't.

Comment: Thanks for helping and giving me how to inform others about the resolution.